# Sushi Bar Prob in cpp(semaphores)

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore, mutual-exclusion

I'm trying to implement a solution for the infamous Sushi Bar Problem. It goes like this: There are only 5 seats in a sushi bar, if all 5 seats are full, new customers should wait for everyone to leave first, and then they take seats until all 5 seats are full again. Below is the function `void * sushiBar(void * threadID)`, the thread ID is actually the index of the thread running the function that I created in main(), they go from 0 to n.

```
void * sushiBar(void * threadID)
{
    usleep(rand() %1000);

    sem_wait(&mutex1);
    if(must_wait)
    {
        printf("Thread[%d]: %d seats are empty but I wait. There are %d other people waiting.\n", *(int*)threadID, 5-eating, waiting);
        waiting += 1;
        sem_post(&mutex1);
        sem_wait(&block);
        waiting -= 1;
    }
    if(eating ==4)
        printf("Thread[%d]: I sit on the last seat, we are dining together now.\n",*(int*)threadID);
    else
    {
        printf("Thread[%d]: There are %d empty seats, so I sit.\n", *(int*)threadID, 5-eating);
    }

    eating += 1;
    must_wait = (eating == 5);

    if(waiting && (!must_wait))
        sem_post(&block);
    else
        sem_post(&mutex1);

    usleep((rand() % 901) + 100);
    sem_wait(&mutex1);
    eating -= 1;
    printf("Thread[%d]: I leave so %d seats are empty now.\n", *(int*)threadID, 5-eating);
    if(eating == 0)
        must_wait = false;
    if ( waiting && (!must_wait))
        sem_post(&block);
    else
        sem_post(&mutex1);
    return 0;

}
```

The given variables are global and initialized as such:

```
int eating = 0, waiting = 0;
bool must_wait = false;
sem_t block;                                                            
sem_t mutex1;
```

mutex1 and block variables are initialized in main this way:

```
sem_init(&mutex1, 0, 1);
sem_init(&block, 0, 0);
```

I'm getting very wrong results with empty seats like -25 and everyone eating at the same time. What should I do to fix this?
Edit: Heres sample output below

`Thread[1]: There are 5 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[5]: There are 4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[13]: There are 3 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[4]: There are 2 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[13]: I leave so 2 seats are empty now.
    Thread[1]: I leave so 3 seats are empty now.
    Thread[4]: I leave so 4 seats are empty now.
    Thread[9]: There are 4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[0]: There are 4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[18]: There are 4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[7]: I sit on the last seat, we are dining together now.
    Thread[10]: 0 seats are empty but I wait. There are 0 other people waiting.
    Thread[16]: 0 seats are empty but I wait. There are 0 other people waiting.
    Thread[10]: There are 0 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[16]: There are 0 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[9]: I leave so -1 seats are empty now.
    Thread[14]: There are -2 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[11]: There are -2 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[2]: There are -2 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[15]: There are -4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[12]: There are -4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[7]: I leave so -4 seats are empty now.
    Thread[8]: There are -4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[6]: There are -4 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[5]: I leave so -5 seats are empty now.
    Thread[0]: I leave so -5 seats are empty now.
    Thread[19]: There are -5 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[3]: There are -5 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[17]: There are -7 empty seats, so I sit.
    Thread[12]: I leave so -7 seats are empty now.
    Thread[16]: I leave so -6 seats are empty now.
    Thread[3]: I leave so -5 seats are empty now.
    Thread[6]: I leave so -4 seats are empty now.
    Thread[15]: I leave so -3 seats are empty now.
    Thread[11]: I leave so -2 seats are empty now.
    Thread[2]: I leave so -1 seats are empty now.
    Thread[18]: I leave so 0 seats are empty now.
    Thread[19]: I leave so 1 seats are empty now.
    Thread[8]: I leave so 2 seats are empty now.
    Thread[14]: I leave so 3 seats are empty now.
    Thread[10]: I leave so 4 seats are empty now.
    Thread[17]: I leave so 5 seats are empty now.
    Program ended with exit code: 0`

Comment: Show your 'logging' output

Comment: You refer to all these variables in `sushiBar` such as `must_wait`, `eating`, and `mutex1`, but you don't show how or when those variables are declared and initialized. Are they globals? For all we know you're not initializing them at all before calling `sushiBar`.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I've edited and added a sample output for a 20 thread array.

Comment: @CareyGregory I've added the initialisations of each variable in the function.

Comment: Why are you using two separate semaphores and doing all that locking and unlocking? It appears to me that you're quite likely modifying global variables with no lock in place, and that's guaranteed to produce strange results. Why not just lock `mutex1` on entry to the function, unlock it on exit, get rid of `block` entirely, and delete all that extra locking and unlocking? I can't see any reason for it.

Comment: @CareyGregory The algorithm is given here http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/LittleBookOfSemaphores.pdf on page 193.

Comment: would you consider using [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) instead of `sem_t`?? Or do you have(feel) the obligation to use `sem_t`?

Comment: @J.Baoby Unfortunately the code must be written in c not c++